# Multiple custom master pages crosstalk

Tags: custom-masterpage

I have a master page 'Master1' that is used on my main site collection.

I have a second master page 'Master1_min' that is used on only one sub-site in the site collection.

'Master1_min' is set as the master page for that sub-site.

However, when I try and debug 'Master1_min' the breakpoints in the code-behind for 'Master1' hit, and the .master for 'Master1_min' is what is displayed.

So essentially the code being run is from 'Master1' and the pages in the browser look like 'Master1_min'.

They are two seperate solutions developed in VS2010, and deployed using their respective .wsp files in powershell.

Any ideas as to why this may happen?

Comment: Can you check to see what the minified masterpage is inheriting from? Is the codebehind set for that masterpage correct?

Comment: You know I just checked that, and it was referenced to the other master. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @spevilgenius can you post that as an answer so you get credit?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to see what the minified masterpage is inheriting from? Is the codebehind set for that masterpage correct?